# Emails sent via GMail send API are being sent twice, intermittently

Tags: php, gmail-api

I am sending messages using the Gmail send API. Here is a distillation of the code (simplified to take out some of my class structure).

```
    $email = 'someone@somewhere.com'
    $textRFC822 = '...' // The email headers and body encoded using PHPMailer
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setAuthConfig('/path/to/google-api-service-client.json');
    $client->setSubject($email);
    $client->addScope('https://mail.google.com/');
    $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
    $message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message();
    $message->setRaw(rtrim(strtr(base64_encode($textRFC822), '+/', '-_'), '='));
    return $service->users_messages->send($email, $message);
```

Most of the time, everything works fine. However, recently, some of the messages have started being sent twice. I have verified that my send code is only being called once, however, the recipient gets two messages which are identical apart from having different message ids (and various other things as a consequence - the DKIM signatures are slightly different, as are the various IDs during the receipt process.

Here are the main differences:

```
<        dkim=pass header.i=@bachtrack.com header.s=google header.b=S+pvQTeu;
---
>        dkim=pass header.i=@bachtrack.com header.s=google header.b=lj29Pf4P;

<        dkim=pass header.i=@bachtrack.com header.s=google header.b=S+pvQTeu;
---
>        dkim=pass header.i=@bachtrack.com header.s=google header.b=lj29Pf4P;

< Message-ID: <CADR-+NC8eFMsOdMn29SGhJtia20TfF61tzr9Quou9DcrdUvYPQ@mail.gmail.com>
---
> Message-ID: <CADR-+NAMrnCOEBCCXFdFJUXOMw_UhkHdrsHuOVsiSJK=66kumQ@mail.gmail.com>
75c75
< Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000c3497d05e47be105"
---
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000c36fb905e47be1e0"

< X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGRyM1vcReoTwVH4rhyVsBoxrkfBeYCqULuFAShT/9fBxY0V/tMh4XiYzPVfpJp/2IsBVXsIKWZwQA4JkXDVKTC53eU=
< X-Received: by 2002:a05:600c:211:b0:3a3:194d:7282 with SMTP id
<  17-20020a05600c021100b003a3194d7282mr3353380wmi.132.1658595603327; Sat, 23 Jul 2022 10:00:03 -0700 (PDT)
---
> X-Google-Smtp-Source: AGRyM1t195t5QQET6GsZQ0a497OwVlFKBtOySVdV9tiO2QRvy5Uv4l8V9jn42S2YtnARvoBp6y4QPWvroOTs84qhv0s=
> X-Received: by 2002:a05:6000:1563:b0:21d:9d8b:9b9d with SMTP id
>  3-20020a056000156300b0021d9d8b9b9dmr3071775wrz.421.1658595603337; Sat, 23 Jul 2022 10:00:03 -0700 (PDT)
```

Any ideas as to why this might be happening, and how to prevent it?

Comment: I don't think this is reproducible, based on the information that was provided. Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: I can easily produce a minimal example. More difficult is to make one that's reproducible. I've had identical messages which sometimes behave correctly, and sometimes get sent twice. I'll work on it...